# No function dropdown in AnimationEvent in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, animator

I try to handle some events during animations, but everywhere I look, every tutorial have access to AnimatorEvent Inspector like this:
[image]
A nice simple field, where you can select a function, I want this!
But instead of this, I always getting this sick 5 fields view, and don't have any idea how to handle animation event in this case!
[image]
I tried to create function test() with debug log, but it didn't work anyway. Why I can't get access to this simple window where I can choose an function?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add this animation into a State in Animator Controller (via Animator Window).

In the object which contains Animator component, attach your script component to it.

Open the Animation window, select the object above, you will see a dropdown of animations (top left) which Animator Controller of this object contains. Choose and add event to the animation you want to.

Select the event in Animation Window, in the Inspector, you should see the dropdown of public functions of your script component attached above.

[Answer by Aluminium18](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1829710/animation-event-not-using-dropdown-menu.html)

Comment: I nasweryed to your answer.

Comment: Ok I found it, it's not simple to find it out, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it doesn't work even if you do all things according to tutorials or advices in internet. I often leave Unity editor launched for a long time without any interactions with it. After several gibernations and several days it can get buggy - various errors appear, you can't see some functions from scripts and so on. So, **just reloading the Unity editor solves many of such issues for me**. And it continues to happen so for several years no matter what Unity version you have. I tried versions from 2019.x.x to 2022.x.x - all this time Unity behaves itself the same.

Answer (score -1):

If y'all have already added the animation to controller then just go to animation window and then "select the object to which animator is attached" and finally add the animation event. Damn sure that will fix this exact problem.