# How to get info about completion of one of my animations in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, 2d

I have monster named Fungant in my 2D platform game.
It can hide as mushroom and rise to his normal form.
I try to handle it in code, but I don't know how to get information about finished animation (without it, animation of rising and hiding always was skipped).
I think the point there is to get info about complete of the one of two animations - Rise and Hide.
There is current code:

```
if (
            fungantAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Fungant Rise")
        )
        {
            fungantAnimator.SetBool("isRising", false);
            isRisen = true;
 
 
            fungantRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(
            walkSpeed * Mathf.Sign(
                player.transform.position.x - transform.position.x),
                fungantRigidbody.velocity.y
            );
        }
 
        if (fungantAnimator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Fungant Hide"))
        {
            fungantAnimator.SetBool("isHiding", false);
            isRisen = false;
        }
```

I try this two ways:

## StateMachineBehaviour

I would like to get StateMachineBehaviour, but how to get it?
No idea how to process this further.

## AnimationEvents

Tried to do with animation event but every tutorial have list of functions to choose (looks easy), but in my Unity I can write Function, Float, Int, String or select object (what I should do?).

I decided to write test() function with Debug only inside, and create AnimationEvents with written "test()" in function field, but nothing happens.

Same as above, no more ideas how to process this further.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use animation events for this. Just add an event to the animation and then the event plays a function after the animation transition is finished.

For more information on how to use animation events you can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71582954/no-function-dropdown-in-animationevent-in-unity).

[This](https://answers.unity.com/questions/986725/animator-event-at-the-end-of-transition.html) post may also help you to add an event when the animation is finished.

I hope this answer helps you to solve this problem.